# How to store a sparse boolean vector in a database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, range, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have a book with ~2^40 pages. Each day, I read a random chunk of contiguous pages (sometimes including some pages I've already read). What's the smartest way to store and update the information of "which pages I've read" in a (SQLite) database ?

My current idea is to store [firstChunkPage, lastChunkPage] entries in a table, but I'm not sure about how to update this efficiently.

- Should I first check for every possible overlaps and then update ?
- Should I just insert my new range and then merge overlapping entries (perhaps multiple times because multiple overlaps can occur ?) ? I'm not sure about how to build such a SQL query.

This looks like a pretty common problem, so I'm wondering if anyone knows a 'recognized' solution for this.

Any help or idea is welcome !

EDIT : The reading isn't actually random, the number of chunks is expected to be pretty much constant and very small compared to the number of pages.

Comment: How do you plan to detemine whether a given page is read or not. A loop from 0 to 2^40?

Comment: No, just a query like "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE firstChunkPage <= page AND page <= lastChunkPage"

Comment: what is expected average data distribution? How many entries are to be stored (min, max, average)? How sparse it is? Because answer would greatly differ for 10% sparseness and 0.00000000001% sparseness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to store ranges of `(firstChunkPage, lastChunkPage)` pairs should work if data is relatively sparse.

Unfortunately, queries like you mentioned:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
WHERE firstChunkPage <= page AND page <= lastChunkPage
```

cannot work effectively, unless you use *spatial indexes*.

For SQLite, you should use [R-Tree module](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html), which implements support for this kind of index. Quote:

> An R-Tree is a special index that is designed for doing range queries. R-Trees are most commonly used in geospatial systems where each entry is a rectangle with minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates. ... For example, suppose a database records the starting and ending times for a large number of events. A R-Tree is able to quickly find all events, for example, that were active at any time during a given time interval, or all events that started during a particular time interval, or all events that both started and ended within a given time interval.

With R-Tree, you can very quickly identify all overlaps before inserting new range and replace them with new combined entry.

To create your RTree index, use something like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE demo_index USING rtree(
    id, firstChunkPage, lastChunkPage
);
```

For more information, [read documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html).

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I'm looking for indeed. Does that imply that there is no native efficient support for "WHERE x <= y" like requests ?

Comment: I don't think you need a spatial index for this. For single-dimensional interval queries, a normal index should work fine. (but check the query plan to be sure)